# Unexpected Return (LocalJumpError)

Tags: ruby, ruby-2.0

What is the problem with this Ruby 2.0 code?

```
p (1..8).collect{|denom|
    (1...denom).collect{|num|
        r = Rational(num, denom)
        if r > Rational(1, 3) and r < Rational(1, 2)
            return 1
        else
            return 0
        end
    }
}.flatten
```

The error is     in `block (2 levels) in <main>': unexpected return (LocalJumpError)`. I want to create a flat list containing *n* ones (and the rest zeroes) where *n* is the number of rational numbers with denominators below 8 which are between 1/3 and 1/2. ([it's a Project Euler problem](http://projecteuler.net/problem=73)). So I'm trying to return from the inner block.

Comment: Don't use `return` in a block. Just remove both `return` and your code will be ok.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You can't `return` inside a block in Ruby<sup>*</sup>. The last statement becomes the return value, so you can just remove the return statements in your case:

```
p (1..8).collect{|denom|
    (1...denom).collect{|num|
        r = Rational(num, denom)
        if r > Rational(1, 3) and r < Rational(1, 2)
            1
        else
            0
        end
    }
}.flatten
```

<sup>*</sup>: You can inside `lambda` blocks: `lambda { return "foo" }.call # => "foo"`. It has to do with scoping and all that, and this is one of the main differences between `lambda` blocks and `proc` blocks. "Normal" blocks you pass to methods are more like `proc` blocks.

Comment: You *can* use `return` inside a block in Ruby. It will return from the enclosing method. In this case, there *is no* enclosing method, *that's* why there is an error, it's *not* because `return` in a block is illegal.

Comment: @JörgWMittag You're right, I was simplifying. `return` returns for the nearest method *or* `lambda` block that you're inside. If you're not inside any, you'll get a `LocalJumpError`.

Comment: @JörgWMittag thanks for this clarifying statement. The answer was confusing as-is and you clarified it. I understand now why this error comes up in irb easily.

Comment: [i feel] this answer definitely needs to be updated with @JörgWMittag's comment because the answer is still technically wrong. I would appreciate if one of you could go in and re-explain the answer with "enclosing method" explained as well with an example of what would work and what wouldn't.

Comment: @JörgWMittag care for a snippet?

Comment: @OK999: `def foo; yield end; def bar; foo { return } end; bar`

Comment: [Starting with Ruby 2.4](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/750f1a39882910dd6357550e2187c264e3d7f0b5/doc/NEWS-2.4.0#language-changes) one can use `return` outside of a method. Feature request is [here](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/4840).

Comment: The phrase @JörgWMittag used "it will return from the enclosing method" is open to misunderstanding. It returns from the method where the block was CREATED not, as many people assume, from the method where the block was CALLED.

Comment: @ComDubh: Normally, when we say "enclosing", we mean "lexically enclosing". (That is really the only sensible interpretation.) The method where the block was called, doesn't lexically enclose the `return`, in fact, it has no syntactic relationship whatsoever (the relationship is purely dynamic).

Comment: @JörgWMittag Agreed, but many developers think that if, during the execution of `foo(a_proc)`, `a_proc` returns, this will cause `foo` to return. Of course it won't, it will cause the method (or lambda body) enclosing the *creation* of `a_proc` to return. Perhaps you don't agree this is a common misunderstanding? I've seen it several blogs and SO answers.

Comment: @ComDubh Definitely a common misunderstanding, in fact it's why I came to this discussion

Answer (score 1):

In ruby, Rather than using a `return` which will return from the enclosing method, you can instead safely use `next` keyword to return value from a block, so your code basically becomes:

```
p (1..8).collect{|denom|
(1...denom).collect{|num|
    r = Rational(num, denom)
    if r > Rational(1, 3) and r < Rational(1, 2)
        next 1
    else
        next 0
    end
   }
}.flatten
```