# LocalJumpError: unexpected return on all db queries after ugrading to rails 4

Tags: database, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-4.1

I'm in the process of ugrading my Rails 3.2 app to Rails 4.1. (I'm using rbx-2.2.10)

I've got to the stage where I'm running my specs, but they fail whenever they query the db and I get this error:

```
LocalJumpError: unexpected return
```

I tried to investigate in my console and I get the same issue when running a query.

I have read a few answers such as this one:

[Unexpected Return (LocalJumpError)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17800629/unexpected-return-localjumperror)

about rails not allowing return calls inside of blocks which are not inside closing methods, but the code that is failing does not have such code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The errors I got were not helpful but I found the problem.

Rails4 now requires that scopes are defined using procs or lambdas. see [this documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html#upgrading-from-rails-3-2-to-rails-4-0-active-record)

> Rails 4.0 requires that scopes use a callable object such as a Proc or
>   lambda:

```
scope :active, where(active: true)
```

> becomes

```
scope :active, -> { where active: true }
```

By changing all of my model scopes to use lambdas, the issue was solved and I can query the db again.

It seems that even one outdated scope ruins all db calls.