# Using `return` in ruby `each` method

Tags: ruby, return

I am trying to create a code that does search and returns its array location when I type the search name. The following code works (`'Ned'` correctly displays value of `1`):

```
array1 = ['Lucky', 'Ned', "Dusty'"]
counter = 0

name = 'Ned'
array1.each do |lookup|
  if lookup == name
    puts counter
  end
  counter += 1
end
```

However, when I use `return counter` in the place of `puts counter`, the code returns error. Here is the error code:

```
unexpected return
(repl):7:in `block in initialize'
(repl):5:in `each'
(repl):5:in `initialize'
```

I don't understand why it says `initialize`. I do not understand why it works with `puts` and does not work with `return`. Will someone explain why it cannot `return` the value while it successfully prints it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unexpected Return (LocalJumpError)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17800629/unexpected-return-localjumperror)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because `return` is a way to escape **from a method (definition)**. You don't have a method definition anywhere. You can use `break` for that purpose.