# Running a Ruby Proc in class scope

Tags: ruby, functional-programming

I've been scratching my head over how to add behaviour to a specific instance
of a class in Ruby. If I use instance_exec like below however the method that calls the proc does not execute all of the way through.

```
class HasSecret
    def initialize(x)
        @secret = x
    end

    def doTheThing(&block)
        puts "before block"
        instance_exec(@secret, &block)
        puts "after block"
    end
end

foo = HasSecret.new(5)
foo.doTheThing do |x|
        puts "x"
        return x
end
```

This example simply gives:

> before block
>
> 5

Is there any perscribed approach to doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
foo.doTheThing do |x|
  puts x
end
```

Generally, you are not supposed to `return` in blocks.  Calling `return` in a block will cause the method yielding (enclosing) to return, which is usually not the behaviour desired.  It can also case a `LocalJumpError`.

In fact, because this scenario is so nuanced and uncommon, a lot of people say you *can't* `return` from a block.  Check out the conversation in the comments of the answer on this question, for example: [Unexpected Return (LocalJumpError)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17800629/unexpected-return-localjumperror/)

In your case, you aren't seeing the "after block" puts because the return in the passed block is causing `doTheThing` to return before getting there.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the other thread.

I'll see if I can use lambdas instead.

Comment: "Calling return in a block will cause the method yielding (enclosing) to return" -- no, it will cause the method that created the block to return.