# How to reject or select based on more than one condition in Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby

An API I’m using returns different content depending on circumstances.

Here’s a snippet of what the API might return:

```
pages = [
  {
    'id' => 100,
    'content' => {
      'score' => 100
    },
  },
  {
    'id' => 101,
    'content' => {
      'total' => 50
    },
  },
  {
    'id' => 102,
  },
]
```

`content` is optional, and can contain different items.

I would like to return a list of pages where the `score` is more than 75.

So far this is as small as I can make it:

```
pages.select! do |page|
  page['content']
end
pages.select! do |page|
  page['content']['score']
end
pages.select! do |page|
  page['content']['score'] > 75
end
```

If I was using JavaScript, I would do this:

```
pages.select(page => {
    if (!page['content'] || !page['content']['score']) {
        return false
    }
    return page['content']['score'] > 75
})
```

Or perhaps if I was using PHP, I would `array_filter` in a similar way.

However, trying to do the same thing in Ruby throws this error:

```
LocalJumpError: unexpected return
```

I understand [why you cannot do that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17800629/unexpected-return-localjumperror). I just want to find a simple way to achieve this in Ruby.

---

Here’s my make-believe Ruby I want to magically work:

```
pages = pages.select do |page|
  return unless page['content']
  return unless page['content']['score']
  page['content']['score'] > 75
end
```

Comment: It would be great if you can paste ruby code here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `dig`, which can access to nested keys in a hash, it returns nil if it can't access to at least one of them, then use the safe operator to do the comparison:

```
p pages.select { |page| page.dig('content', 'score')&.> 75 }
# [{"id"=>100, "content"=>{"score"=>100}}]
```

Notice this "filter" is done in one step, so you don't need to mutate your object.

For your *make-belive* approach, you need to replace the `return`s with `next`:

```
pages = pages.select do |page|
  next unless page['content']
  next unless page['content']['score']
  page['content']['score'] > 75
end

p pages # [{"id"=>100, "content"=>{"score"=>100}}]
```

There `next` is used to skip the rest of the current iteration.

---

You can save one line in that example, if you use fetch and pass as the default value an empty hash:

```
pages.select do |page|
  next unless page.fetch('content', {})['score']

  page['content']['score'] > 75
end
```

Same way you can do just `page.fetch('content', {}).fetch('score', 0) > 75` (but better don't).

Comment: Keep in mind though that `dig` was introduced in Ruby 2.4, if I remember correctly, so you can't use this approach in earlier versions.

Comment: Thanks @MarekLipka, I hope he doesn't have problems using dig, I can't think in a cleaner example without using that method.

Comment: This is a good answer, but: "`next` in an enumerator returns the next object, and move the internal position forward. When the position reached at the end, StopIteration is raised." I think you're conflating [`next` keyword](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6/doc/syntax/control_expressions_rdoc.html#label-next+Statement) with the  [`Enumerator#next` method](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Enumerator.html#method-i-next). Your code users the former, but your description concerns the latter.

Comment: Oh, yes @JordanRunning, sorry for that. I've updated that part, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use logical "and" (`&&`) to concatenate conditions

```
pages.select! do |page|
  page['content'] && page['content']['score'] && page['content']['score'] > 75
end
```

Comment: Thanks for this – my conditions get quite complex, so my line length would become horrible to read quite quickly. But perfectly valid answer!

Comment: You can move it to a separate method/labdas (or set of lambdas/methods)

Answer (score 1):

You can actually achieve this using `lambda`, where `return` means what you expect it to mean:

```
l = lambda do |page|
  return false if !page['content'] || !page['content']['score']

  page['content']['score'] > 75
end

pages.select(&l)
# => [{"id"=>100, "content"=>{"score"=>100}}]
```

but I guess it's not very practical.